# Executing Javascript on Firefox with Selenium in a Java Test Automation Framework

Tags: javascript, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am using a Test Automation Framework that uses Java with Selenium.
I am trying to execute some Javascript on a website, so I move to the URL and then I run the following command to execute the javascript:

```
webDriver.executeScript("sdkInstance.authenticate(xxxxx'});");
```

When I run this on Chrome, Edge and Safari, it works fine and I am successfully authenticated.

However when I run it on Firefox, I get a response saying 'sdkInstance' is not defined.

I have tried running it AUTOMATED on my local Firefox and also on Browserstack Firefox and I get the same response.

*[Note: If I manually open a Firefox browser, browse to the URL, go to Web Developer, Web Console and then copy the command above in, it works fine.]*

Am I missing something fundamental in order to execute Javascript on Firefox with Selenium?

Comment: Are there different variables created in Firefox? If it doesn't work when you run it manually on FF, why would you expect it to work through automation?

Comment: If I manually open a Firefox browser, browse to the URL, go to Web Developer, Web Console and then copy the command above in, it works. However it doesn't work when I run it using webDriver.executeScript on Firefox.

Comment: Sounds like there's probably a timing issue. To debug, add a 5 second wait or something like that to ensure that the page is loaded before running your JS code... does it work now?